# the operation of "=" in javascript

Tags: javascript

consider the following code

```
var pub_json_general = {"holis":["12/10/2013","12/25/2013","12/26/2013"]};
var holiday = {"holis":["12/02/2013"]};
var pub_json = pub_json_general;
pub_json.holis = $.merge(pub_json.holis,holiday.holis);
```

After merge, the length of pub_json.holis becomes 4, that's correct. However, when I use firefox debugger, I found that pub_json_general.holis would also be changed, that means pub_json_general and pub_json would always be the same.

So is that "=" operation in javascript is not copying the right-hand side and create the left-hand side to store it but just create the left-hand side which will share the the same memory space with right-hand side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you have explained everything correctly by yourself :)

For reference types, the <strike>equality</strike> [**assignment** operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) assigns reference to the object, it does not clone the object. Therefore when you change one, the other changes too.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this question [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) to solve your problem

Comment: Everything in JS is pass **by value**. In case of objects, the value happens to be a reference to the object. That is not the same as *pass by reference*!

Comment: You're right, my bad. It was an unfortunate mental shortcut. I've deleted the misleading sentence

Answer (score 1):

> So is that "=" operation in javascript is not copying the right-hand side and create the left-hand side to store it but just create the left-hand side which will share the the same memory space with right-hand side?

This is a very confusing question. If you are trying to understand what is happening in the last statement, here it is:

1. The expression `$.merge(pub_json.holis,holiday.holis)` is evaluated. As a result, the contents of `holiday.holis` are appended to the array residing at `pub_json.holis` (which is the same array as the one referred to by `pub_json_general.holis`).

   The result of the expression is the newly altered `pub_json.holis` array.
2. The result from 1, `pub_json.holis`, is assigned to `pub_json.holis`, which understandably does nothing, and is a non-op.